# Convert and validate string

Tags: c++, algorithm, console-application, std

I need to take time as user input in the form HH:MM and then validate it.
It needs to be a proper time in that certain format. Any good Ideas on how to do that?

I'm trying to make a function that will iterate through the string, validating each character, then convert them into numbers (or some kind of time stamp) so I can compare several strings to eachother.

I'm only using the std namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be overkill for this particular problem, but this kind of task is a great fit for a state machine. Basically, you'll want to read the input one character at a time, and each character can change the machine's state until you end up in a success or error state. For example:

1. First character

   - If not a number, change to error state
   - Otherwise store value and change to state 2
2. Second character

   - If not a number, change to error state
   - Otherwise multiply stored value by 10 and add second character. If the result is out of range, change to error state. Otherwise, change to state 3
3. Third character

   - If `:`, change to state 4, otherwise change to error state
4. Fourth character

   - Similar to First character, changing to state 5 upon success.
5. Fifth character

   - Similar to Second character, changing to state 6 upon success.
6. Success state

   - A winner is yuo!
7. Error state

   - Handle the error, duh.

Answer (score 2):

Use boost::regex to match string and its parts (HH) and (MM) and use scanf to get hours and minutes.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds more like an algorithm problem, I would:

1, check the length of the string if it's 5.
2, check if ':' is in the middle.
3, check HH is in the range.
4, check MM is in the range.
5, Convert it to the format which will bring convenience to you.