# How to validate input string in short time format

Tags: c++, validation, time-format

I've got an input string which is to represent a 24h time. Valid inputs are strings like:

> 7:04
>   07:4
>   7:4
>   07:04

And an invalid input string would be obviously something like `25:68`. Is there any easy way to **validate** the time format, and then **parse** the time in epoch format given that the time is of today? Is there possibly any boost library that comes handy here?

Comment: [Regular expressions?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using strptime, which is standard on Unix-like systems:
http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strptime.3.html

Answer (score 2):

I see two options:

1. Simple regex or boost::xpressive (I like it more).
2. Get the numbers between semicolon and convert them to numbers, then check their values. Something like this:

   > ```
   > string sTime("53:30");
   > int iSemiColon = sTime.find(':');       
   > if (atoi(sTime.substr(0, iSemiColon).c_str()) >= 24) return false;
   > if (atoi(sTime.substr(iSemiColon + 1).c_str()) >= 60) return false;
   > ```

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005842/convert-and-validate-string/14007098#14007098). If you're not limited to STL, you could use `boost.Regex` for the validation part, though it's such a simple problem that you could easily roll your own solution.